# add variables in php string literal

Tags: php, literals

Is it possible to add variables in a php string literal?  Something like:

```
echo "<td>{$j} + {$i}</td>";
```

or

```
echo "<td>{$j + $i}</td>";
```

but neither of those work

Comment: Just `echo "<td>" . ($j + $i) . "</td>";`, no?

Comment: No, PHP doesn't have anything like Python f-strings or JavaScript template literals.

Comment: You can substitute variables in strings, but not expressions.

Comment: No, you can't add up string literals directly in a string syntax in `PHP`

Comment: But if you assign some function that sums numbers to a variable, and put this variable into a string like `{$var()}`, you can achieve what you want))))